# Mostrar un campo calculado como la suma o resta de un campo según otro campo

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

Tengo el siguiente modelo en Django con transaccione que se dividen en ingresos y salidas de mercadería. (Si alguno no sabe django, pero sabría como sería la sentencia SQL ayudaría igualmente)

```
class Movimientos(models.Model):
    movimientos = [
    ('ING', 'INGRESO'),
    ('SAL', 'SALIDA'),
    ]
    estados = [
    ('PRO', 'PROCESADO'),
    ('ANA', 'ANALIZADO'),
    ('PEN', 'PENDIENTE'),
    ('CAN', 'CANCELADO'),
    ]

    cantidad_um=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
    precio_por_um=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
    mat_um=models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=True)
    orden_compra_mov=models.ForeignKey(Ordenes_Compra,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo_movimiento=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=movimientos, blank=True, null=True)
    estado_movimiento=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=estados, blank=True, null=True) 
    cantidad_um_analizada=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
```

Estos movimientos los quiero reflejar en una tabla y tengo esta vista en donde le quiero sumar la cantidad total de cada producto en base a los movimientos de ingreso y salida:

Los movimientos que tengan "tipo_movimiento" "ING"  (ingreso) o "SAL" (salida) y la columna del total debería sumar las cantidades de tipo de movimiento "ING" y restar las de "SAL"

En la vista que les pongo abajo solo estoy sumando los movimientos de ingreso, ¿COMO PODRÍA HACER PARA RESTARLES LOS DE SALIDA?

```
movimientos = Movimientos.objects.values(
    'mat_um__cod_material',
    'mat_um__unidad_medida',
    'orden_compra_mov__comedor__nombre_centro',
    'mat_um__nombre_material'
    ).annotate(suma_cant = (Sum('cantidad_um')).filter(tipo_movimiento="ING"))
            
return render(request, 'app/stock.html', {'facturas': movimientos})
```

Gracias!

Comment: Lo otro que pensé es almacenar las salidas como valores negativos, pero no se que sea lo correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver el tema con expresiones condicionales de Django, usando filter como argumento de la función SUM, les dejo el link de la documentación sobre EXPRESIONES CONDICIONALES:

[DOCUMENTACIÓN DJANGO](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

La vista en definitiva me quedó así:

```
def stock(request):

movimientos = Movimientos.objects.values(
    'mat_um__cod_material',
    'mat_um__unidad_medida',
    'orden_compra_mov__comedor__nombre_centro',
    'mat_um__nombre_material'
    ).annotate(
        suma_cant = Sum('cantidad_um', filter = Q(tipo_movimiento = 'ING' )),
        resta_cant = Sum('cantidad_um', filter = Q(tipo_movimiento = 'SAL' )),
        total=F('suma_cant')-F('resta_cant'))
            
return render(request, 'app/stock.html', {'facturas': movimientos})
```

Si alguno tiene otra manera de representar lo mismo ayudaría mucho, para tener más herramientas y opciones para resolver problemas.

Saludos,